# Lua Pattern Matching issue

Tags: lua, pattern-matching

I'm trying to parse a text file using lua and store the results in two arrays. I thought my pattern would be correct, but this is the first time I've done anything of the sort.

**fileio.lua**:

```
questNames = {}
questLevels = {}
lineNumber = 1

file = io.open("results.txt", "w")
io.input(file)

for line in io.lines("questlist.txt") do
  questNames[lineNumber], questLevels[lineNumber]= string.match(line, "(%a+)(%d+)")
  lineNumber = lineNumber + 1
end

for i=1,lineNumber do
  if (questNames[i] ~= nil and questLevels[i] ~= nil) then
    file:write(questNames[i])
    file:write(" ")
    file:write(questLevels[i])
    file:write("\n")
  end
end

io.close(file)
```

Here's a small snippet of **questlist.txt**:

`If the dead could talk16
Forgotten soul16
The Toothmaul Ploy9
Well-Armed Savages9`

And here's a matching snippet of **results.txt**:

`talk 16
soul 16
Ploy 9
Savages 9`

What I'm after in **results.txt** is:

`If the dead could talk 16
Forgotten soul 16
The Toothmaul Ploy 9
Well-Armed Savages 9`

So my question is, which pattern do I use in order to select all text up to a number?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%a` matches letters. It does not match spaces.

If you want to match *everything* up to a sequence of digits you want `(.-)(%d+)`.

If you want to match a leading sequence of non-digits then you want `([^%d]+)(%d+)`.

That being said if all you want to do is insert a space before a sequence of digits then you can just use `line:gsub("%d+", " %0", 1)` to do that (the one to only do it for the first match, leave that off to do it for every match on the line).

As an aside I don't think `io.input(file)` is doing anything useful for you (or what you might expect). It is replacing the default standard input file handle with the file handle `file`.

Comment: Thank you, `([^%d]+)(%d+)` is what I'm after. Oh I see, this is my first time using lua properly and the tutorial mentioned it. I'll take it out.

Comment: What tutorial? What did it say about it?

Comment: You probably mean `(.-)(%d+)` instead of `(.*)(%d+)`.

Comment: @lhf Indeed. Thanks.